# Inheriting tests from another repo using github

Tags: git, github

I'm writing a plugin for backbone and want it to always pass the latest version of backbone's tests (plus a few of my own). How can I use git/github to always reference the latest backbone tests in my test runner?

Comment: I would try this: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the backbone repo as a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) of your project.